# How can I get %i Ruby arrays to be properly highlighted in Vim?

Tags: ruby, vim

My Vim is not highlighting the relatively new `%i` syntax. Here's an example:

[image]

I included a `%w` example, which works properly, to show the desired effect.

How can I get Vim to highlight `%i` properly?

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? Try `:version` to see the main version and the patch numbers.

Comment: 8.0, 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283

Answer (score 1):

If you’d type `:syn ⏎` in control mode while editing any ruby file, you’ll see all the syntax definitions (or open system-wide syntax theme for ruby `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/ruby.vim` or where is it located.)

The one responsible for `%i[]` would be `rubySymbol`.

`%i[]` is by no mean “relatively new,” the issue is your color theme does not highlight symbols differently. Not only literals, all the symbols. Run:

```
:hi rubySymbol term=bold ctermfg=Red
```

and you’ll see it perfectly works. You might tune it according to your needs (see e. g. `rubyString` for the inspiration) and put this somewhere in your `~/.vim/syntax/ruby.vim`.

Comment: This doesnt belong in colors. It belongs in `~/.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim` OR as an autocommand for the ColorScheme event

Answer (score 0):

By default, Vim highlights Ruby's string delimiters and symbol delimiters differently. The string delimiters are highlighted as type `Delimiter`, and the symbol delimiters are highlighted the same as symbols, which is, by default, of type `Constant`.

If you want to highlight the `%i` and brackets the same as the `%w`, you can run the following command:

```
:hi link rubySymbolDelimiter rubyStringDelimiter
```

If you like that setting, you can put it in a file called `.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim` and it will be picked up automatically whenever the Ruby syntax is enabled.

Note that in newer versions of Vim, the above command will also cause the colon in front of a symbol to be highlighted the same way as the `%i`. That functionality isn't configurable, since they both use the `rubySymbolDelimiter` match group.

Comment: It's configurable, just not easily (you could change ruby syntax definition for your own). :)

Comment: Well, sure, everything is configurable if you do it yourself. My meaning was, "It's not configurable with the default syntax highlighting definitions as provided."

Comment: To me, "not configurable" is e.g. making a new ex command that starts with a lowercase letter, which you couldn't do without changing Vim source and recompiling; changing Ruby syntax definitions by writing a syntax file in VimScript (such as some plugins have done) is definitely not in the same realm.